# Posting image file from console application to API as an IFormFile parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

I need to upload an image to an API from an Asp.Net Core Console Application.

The API being posted to looks like this and works fine when tested with Postman:

```
[HttpPost("UploadImage")]
public async Task<string> UploadImage(IFormFile files)
{
      // stuff happens here
}
```

What would the code look like to post a file from the console app to this?
Thanks

Comment: Could this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048938/uploading-file-from-console-application-to-webapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to upload an image to an API from an Asp.Net Core Console Application.

To achieve the requirement of making HTTP request to post image from Console app to API backend, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var FilePath = @"D:\xxx\pic1.PNG";

formContent.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(FilePath)), "files", Path.GetFileName(FilePath));

_httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44312/");

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/UploadImage", formContent);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //....
    //code logic here
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a library including formfile operations. ConvertToFormFile method is in my library. But you can't use external assembly because of Memory Stream. So you can define this method in your own class or as a extension method.

```
 public class ProductDTO {

    private string _imageBase64String;
    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ImageBase64String
    {
        get => _imageBase64String;
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                 Image = ConvertToFormFile(value);
            }
            _imageBase64String = value;
        }
    }

    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// Converts data URI formatted base64 string to IFormFile.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="milvaBase64"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IFormFile ConvertToFormFile(string milvaBase64)
    {
        var splittedBase64String = milvaBase64.Split(";base64,");
        var base64String = splittedBase64String?[1];

        var contentType = splittedBase64String[0].Split(':')[1];

        var splittedContentType = contentType.Split('/');

        var fileType = splittedContentType?[0];

        var fileExtension = splittedContentType?[1];

        var array = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(array)
        {
            Position = 0
        };

        return new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, fileType, $"File.{fileExtension}")
        {
            Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
            ContentType = contentType
        };
    }
}
```

Sample data uri formatted base64 string : data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wCEAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDB...

Then you can use my library to save the image or do other things. Like below;

```
public class ProductService{
  
    ...

    private readonly IStringLocalizer<ProductService> _localizer;

    ...

    public async Task SaveProductImage(ProductDTO productDTO)
    {
         
       var imagePath = await productDTO.Image.SaveImageToServerAsync<ProductDTO, int>(productDTO, _localizer).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
 }

public static class HelperExtension{

    /// <summary>
    /// Save uploaded IFormFile file to server. Target Path will be : ".../wwwroot/Media Library/Image Library/<paramref name="entity"></paramref>.Id"
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<string> SaveImageToServerAsync<TEntity, TKey>(this IFormFile file, TEntity entity, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer) where TEntity : AuditableEntity<OpsiyonUser, Guid, TKey>
                                                                                                                                                  where TKey : struct, IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        string basePath = GlobalConstants.ImageLibraryPath;

        FormFileOperations.FilesFolderNameCreator imagesFolderNameCreator = CreateImageFolderNameFromDTO;

        string propertyName = "Id";

        int maxFileLength = 14000000;

        var allowedFileExtensions = GlobalConstants.AllowedFileExtensions.Find(i => i.FileType == FileType.Image.ToString()).AllowedExtensions;

        var validationResult = file.ValidateFile(FileType.Image, maxFileLength, allowedFileExtensions);

        switch (validationResult)
        {
            case FileValidationResult.Valid:
                break;
            case FileValidationResult.FileSizeTooBig:
                // Get length of file in bytes
                long fileSizeInBytes = file.Length;
                // Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
                double fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
                // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
                double fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
                throw new MilvaValidationException(stringLocalizer["FileIsTooBigMessage", fileSizeInMB.ToString("0.#")]);
            case FileValidationResult.InvalidFileExtension:
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                throw new MilvaValidationException(stringLocalizer["UnsupportedFileTypeMessage", stringBuilder.AppendJoin(", ", allowedFileExtensions)]);
            case FileValidationResult.NullFile:
                return "";
        }

        var path = await file.SaveFileToPathAsync(entity, basePath, imagesFolderNameCreator, propertyName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await file.OpenReadStream().DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return path;
    }


    private static string CreateImageFolderNameFromDTO(Type type)
    {
        return type.Name.Split("DTO")[0] + "Images";
    }

}
```

Or you can use this method in FormFileOperations.cs like below;

```
   public async Task<IFormFile> GetFile()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.jpg");

        return await FormFileOperations.GetFileFromPathAsync(path, FileType.Image).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

and send request with HttpClient.

Detailed information about my library please take a look;

[Github link](https://github.com/Milvasoft/Milvasoft/blob/master/Milvasoft.Helpers/FileOperations/Concrete/FormFileOperations.cs)

[Nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Milvasoft.Helpers/)

I haven't created documentation yet, but in-code documentation is available everywhere. I have a goal to turn this into a framework in the future. I will be glad if you contribute.

I hope its helps.